# gdal projection string not recognized by arcpy.SpatialReference()

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, gdal

I have a raster image that has a custom projection system. I used the following code to retrieve the projection information from the raster and turn it into an ArcGIS recognized PCS following [this example](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/classes/spatialreference.htm)...

```
import arcpy
from osgeo import gdal

raster_path = r"\\tiff_inputs\tiff_UTM_inputs\amz_jurisdiction_UTM20.tif"
in_ds = gdal.Open(raster_path)
projection = in_ds.GetProjection()
pcs = arcpy.SpatialReference(text=projection)
```

Here is the projection string when printed to the console...

```
'PROJCS["Brasil, Zona UTM 20, hemisf\udce9rio sul",GEOGCS["br_utm20sad_s",DATUM["South American 1969",SPHEROID["International 1967 (truncated)",6378160,298.24999999573],TOWGS84[-67.35,3.88,-38.22,0,0,0,0]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-63],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",10000000],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]'
```

However when I input this projection string into `arcpy.SpatialReference` I receive the following error:

> ValueError: SpatialReference: Spatial reference string is invalid.

I cannot use the display name of the coordinate system as an input either because it is not recognized by arcpy.

How can I reformat the gdal projection string to be valid parameter for `arcpy.SpatialReference`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating an `osr.SpatialReference()` object from the GDAL WKT, then using  `MorphToESRI()` to make any WKT it spits out ESRI-compatible.

Should look something like this:

```py
from osgeo import osr

gdal_wkt = in_ds.GetProjection()
gdal_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
gdal_srs.ImportFromWkt(gdal_wkt)
gdal_srs.MorphToESRI()
esri_wkt = gdal_srs.ExportToWkt()
esri_srs = arcpy.SpatialReference(text=esri_wkt)
```

Python docs: https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.osr.html#osgeo.osr.SpatialReference.MorphToESRI

C++ docs with a better description: https://gdal.org/doxygen/classOGRSpatialReference.html#aac948450b15fa3d8814ab440b9f705b7

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It appears that my wkt is not valid. I received an error ```TypeError: not a string``` when running ```gdal_srs.ImportFromWkt(gdal_wkt)``` using the projection string that I provided in the post. What do you suspect could be the issue?

Comment: Hmm, well what does `type(gdal_wkt)` give?  If it's `None` then maybe you're trying a raster with no projection defined, or perhaps gdal is already giving back a `SpatialReference`?

Comment: I used encoding and decoding and this fixed my issues with the projection string. ```gdal_wkt = in_ds.GetProjection().encode('utf-8', 'backslashreplace').decode('utf-8')```

Answer (score 0):

While I am not sure why your projection isn't being recognised by ArcGIS Pro, the closest projection to the one you have provided looks like SIRGAS_2000_Brazil_Mercator. Try reprojecting your raster into that via ArcGIS Pro.

[image]

You can access the spatial reference in arcpy by using the following code:

```
pcs = arcpy.SpatialReference('SIRGAS_2000_Brazil_Mercator')
```

Comment: Hi Angus, I am trying to automate this part of the process and use the spatial reference at a later stage.